# Google BigQuery analytics prices

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to analyze about 50GB of data (constantly growing data) using Google BigQuery. But I'm wondering 2 things about bigquery pricing and analytics.

My data content (each row)

*COLUMN | ROW*

**USER_ID** --> Unique User ID (e.g zc5zta5h7a6sr)

**BUY_COUNT** --> INT(e.g 35)

**TOTAL_CURRENCY** --> USD (e.g. 500$)

etc.

The things I want to show in the chart; TOTAL CURRENCY Number of unique users with $1-999 and 1000-10,000+$.

I know that there is a $5 pricing for each 1TB processed in analysis, but;

1-) 1 GB of new data will be added to the BigQuery table every day. I want to create a live graph on each new data. Will Google bigquery only bill for 1GB of analytics added every day, or will it repeatedly analyze 50GB of data and bill 50+1GB with each new data?

2-) Data with the same id can be added to my constantly updated data set. Is it possible to combine them automatically? For example;
Can I update the BUY_COUNT column in the table id when the user with id zc5zta5h7a6sr makes a new purchase? If possible, how will I be billed for it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BigQuery analysis billing occur every time you run a query. About your points:

1. If your query scans the all table every time, you will be billed for the current size of the table each time the query runs. Are some ways to optimize this, such materialized views, partitioned tables, build an aggregated table etc.
2. If your aggregation is not much complex, [materialized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro#storage_cost_details) can help with this point. For e.g., you can have an `raw` table with unnagregated data and an materialized view which aggregate BUY_COUNT by user. You will be billed for the bytes scanned during the automatic maintance plus the bytes scanned every time a query runs on the view.

More info about the pricing: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing